# Cypress: How can i use any variable/element of a describe block in different describe block?

Tags: cypress

```js
//Enter data and add the customer profiles
describe('Enter data to New profiles', function() {
    it('Enter cuatomer details and add the customer profile', function() {

        //Dynamic Customer profile Name

        const todaysDateTime = Cypress.moment().format('MMMDDYYYYSS')
        const profileName = 'ProfileName-' + todaysDateTime
        //Entering the profile Name
        cy.get('input[id="fileDataSubform-portfolio_name"]').type(profileName)
        cy.get('textarea[name="fileDataSubform[customer_list]"]').type('Smith002')
        //clicking the submit button
        cy.get('button[id="pvwButton1"]').click()
    })
})
//I want to use above 'profileName' const value in diffrenet describe block.

describe('Customer details page Navigation', function() {
            it('Click on created customer profile name', function() {
                        cy.get('html > body > div:nth-of-type(1)').then(($elem) => {
                                const x = $elem.text()
                                cy.log(x)
                                if (x.includes(profileName)) {
                                    cy.log("found")
                                    cy.get($elem).click()

                                })
                        })
```

I have used cypres hook method to solve this but is there anyway, I could able to use the 1 dynamic value of a describe block in other describe block apart from cypress hook concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move `profileName` outside of your `describe` so it's in the global scope. Then, it can be accessed from anywhere in the test file.

Read more about Javascript scopes here (it will supercharge your Cypress experience): https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Something like this should work:

```js
const todaysDateTime = Cypress.moment().format('MMMDDYYYYSS')
const profileName = 'ProfileName-' + todaysDateTime

describe('Enter data to New profiles', function() {
  // ... your tests that use profileName here ...
})

describe('Customer details page Navigation', function() {
  // ... more tests that use profileName here ...
})
```